# Parse multiple json passed as string - Socket.io, NodeJS and ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, socket.io

I have a socket connected to a third party and I receive data using websockets. At times data received through socket could have a string containing multiple sets of array.

How to handle this while parsing?

for ex, data I receive normally:

```
[{a:1}, {b:2}, {c:3}]
```

at times, I receive:

```
[{a:1}, {b:2}, {c:3}][{d:1}, {e:2}, {f:3}]
```

and I get below error, because i guess JSON.parse does not know what to do with it:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [ in JSON at position 267
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

I would want to split and parse both json array. so my new output would be:

```
[{a:1}, {b:2}, {c:3}] as arr[0] and  [{d:1}, {e:2}, {f:3}] as arr[1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is to separate the string into an array:

```
var str = "[{a:1}, {b:2}, {c:3}][{d:1}, {e:2}, {f:3}]";
var res = str.replace("][", "]|[");
var arr = res.split("|");
```